# GMail API returns unspeficied error at random moments

Tags: python, google-app-engine, gmail-api

I'm running a Python app on Google App Engine which regularly checks the latest emails for multiple users. I've noticed that at random moments, the API returns the following error:

```
error: An error occured while connecting to the server: Unable to fetch URL: https://www.googleapis.com/discovery/v1/apis/gmail/v1/rest?userIp=0.1.0.2
```

Typically, if the job runs again, it works. Below my code. I would like to understand what is causing this, and more importantly how I can prevent the error from blocking the process (e.g. how to run the job again with the same values when this error is thrown).

```
class getLatest(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):
    try:
      email = self.request.get('email')
      g = Credentials.get_by_id(email)
      REFRESH_TOKEN = g.refresh_token
      start_history_id = g.hid

      credentials = OAuth2Credentials(None, settings.CLIENT_ID,
                             settings.CLIENT_SECRET, REFRESH_TOKEN, None,
                             GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI, None,
                             revoke_uri=GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI,
                             id_token=None,
                             token_response=None)

      http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
      service = discovery.build("gmail", "v1", http=http)
      for n in range(0, 5): 
        try:
          history = service.users().history().list(userId=email, startHistoryId=start_history_id).execute(http=http)
          break
        except errors.HttpError, e:
          if n < 4:
            time.sleep((2 ** n) + random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000)
          else:
            raise
      changes = history['history'] if 'history' in history else []
      while 'nextPageToken' in history:
        page_token = history['nextPageToken']
        for n in range(0, 5): 
          try:
            history = service.users().history().list(userId=email, startHistoryId=start_history_id, pageToken=page_token).execute(http=http)
            break
          except errors.HttpError, e:
            if n < 4:
              time.sleep((2 ** n) + random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000)
            else:
              raise
        changes.extend(history['history'])

    except errors.HttpError, error:
        logging.exception('An error occurred: '+str(error))
        if error.resp.status == 401:
            # Credentials have been revoked.
            # TODO: Redirect the user to the authorization URL.
            raise NotImplementedError()
        else:
            stacktrace = traceback.format_exc()
            logging.exception('%s', stacktrace)
```

UPDATE

I updated the code based on the answer below, however it never seems to run the request multiple times. The process just aborts as soon as an exception takes place.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It turns out it was the same issue as reported [here](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-python-client/issues/detail?id=209). I was hitting the rate limit on requesting the discovery document, which you only need to do once per day. I solved it by implementing the suggested solution on my app. The code can be found in [this Stackoverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31378804/gmail-api-on-gae-correctly-using-discovery-build-from-document).

Answer (score 0):

This error can occur due to multiple reasons including your agent going offline for a moment to exceeding rate limit of Gmail API. You need to retry in case of these temporary issues in a graceful manner. Below is the code edit that may help:

```
class getLatest(webapp2.RequestHandler):
  def post(self):

try:
  email = self.request.get('email')
  g = Credentials.get_by_id(email)
  REFRESH_TOKEN = g.refresh_token
  start_history_id = g.hid

  credentials = OAuth2Credentials(None, settings.CLIENT_ID,
                         settings.CLIENT_SECRET, REFRESH_TOKEN, None,
                         GOOGLE_TOKEN_URI, None,
                         revoke_uri=GOOGLE_REVOKE_URI,
                         id_token=None,
                         token_response=None)

  http = credentials.authorize(httplib2.Http())
  service = discovery.build("gmail", "v1", http=http)
  for n in range(0, 5):  
  try:
      history = service.users().history().list(userId=email, startHistoryId=start_history_id).execute(http=http)
      break
  except Exception as e:
        # Apply exponential backoff.
        time.sleep((2 ** n) + random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000)

  changes = history['history'] if 'history' in history else []
  while 'nextPageToken' in history:
    page_token = history['nextPageToken']

    for n in range(0, 5):  
    try:
       history = service.users().history().list(userId=email, startHistoryId=start_history_id, pageToken=page_token).execute(http=http)
       changes.extend(history['history'])
       break
    except Exception as e:
        # Apply exponential backoff.
        time.sleep((2 ** n) + random.randint(0, 1000) / 1000)
except errors.HttpError, error:
    logging.exception('An error occurred: '+str(error))
    if error.resp.status == 401:
        # Credentials have been revoked.
        # TODO: Redirect the user to the authorization URL.
        raise NotImplementedError()
    else:
        stacktrace = traceback.format_exc()
        logging.exception('%s', stacktrace)
```

Essentially this code retries if an exception occurs at google end from the same point with exponential backoff. Add your error code, for which you want to retry. Hope this resolves your problem.

Comment: I'm guessing adding a break would also be required in order to not run the same query successfully 5 times?

Comment: @Vincent, you are right, corrected my post above. Thanks for pointing it out. It should work now :)

Comment: unfortunately I had to uncheck your answer since the error is still present. Thought it was gone but unfortunately it's not. I have added the updated code above.

Comment: @Vincent I edited my code above to handle gracefully few more exceptions. Please try the updated code and add any other status codes in exception handler if you know them already.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Not sure if it will help though, cause as you can see in my updated code, I actually completely removed the filter for status codes, meaning the code should re-run on any exception...

Comment: @Vincent Just a thought: It may not be an API (httperror) exception that causes your program to halt. Hence changed my code once again to catch general exception and retry if anything happens. Try this one.

Comment: Thanks. I will let this run for a bit and update once I have feedback